# LiveCharts GeoMap

Tags: c#, geolocation, livecharts, geomap, gvisgeomap

```
    var r = new Random();

    var values = new Dictionary<string, double>();

    values["MX"] = r.Next(0, 100);
    values["CA"] = r.Next(0, 100);
    values["US"] = r.Next(0, 100);
    values["IN"] = r.Next(0, 100);
    values["CN"] = r.Next(0, 100);
    values["JP"] = r.Next(0, 100);
    values["BR"] = r.Next(0, 100);
    values["DE"] = r.Next(0, 100);
    values["FR"] = r.Next(0, 100);
    values["GB"] = r.Next(0, 100);

    var lang = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    lang["MX"] = "México"; // change the language if necessary

    geoMap1.HeatMap = values;
    geoMap1.LanguagePack = lang;
    geoMap1.Source = "Maps/World.xml";
}
```

I am using livecharts geoheatmap. I'm trying my code but I want to add the post onto the countries I have selected on the country I want on the map. how can I accomplish this.I want to write text on the map of the country.I'm using livecharts geomapheat. I want to add text on the map. how can I do it?

https://files.gitter.im/beto-rodriguez/Live-Charts/Ra2o/30030517-54083670-9196-11e7-93ae-f51542a61584.png

[image: i want to do that like this]

Comment: And what is your problem? What have you tried?

Comment: i did it now , can you help me please?

Comment: sorry for that...:(

Comment: By settings GeoMap.Hoverable=true in code or xaml, you will get a text tooltip to display with country name with heatmap value.